# Instantiate создает множество копий объекта Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добрый день. Возникла проблема с Unity3D, пытаюсь создать копию объекта в заданной точке. Объект создается, но начинает клонировать сам себя до бесконечности, что не так?

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject pref;
    private GameObject copys;
    private Vector3 copysmest;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        copysmest = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
            copys = Instantiate(pref, copysmest,Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Результат такой:

[image: Результат]

Comment: `что не так?` - логика же. инстанцируется объект со скриптом NewBehaviourScript , у него срабатывает метод `Start`, в котором срабатывает инстанциирование объекта со скриптом NewBehaviourScript у которого срабатывает `Start`  и т.д.....

Comment: А тогда запретить создавать клоны?

Comment: Правильно сделать логику.....вот к примеру `private GameObject copys;` -  жизненно необходим в скрипте? Зачем?

Comment: Вот пример с документации по Unity3d

Comment: // Instantiates 10 copies of prefab each 2 units apart from each other

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform prefab;
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i * 2.0F, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Я делаю тоже самое и у меня виснет unity

Comment: Во-первых - дайте ссылку.... во-вторых - нет, не тоже самое

Comment: вот https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: А теперь покажите мне то место, где в примере есть элемент `copys` внутри **этого же** скрипта? Еще раз спрошу:   `private GameObject copys;` - жизненно необходим в скрипте? Зачем?

Comment: Да я согласен с Вами, но я имел ввиду, что если пишу код который есть в документации unity виснет

Comment: Код первоначальный был такой

Comment: public GameObject pref;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
       Instantiate(pref, new Vector3(10, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }

Comment: `что если пишу код который есть в документации unity виснет` - тот код, что есть в документации - **НЕ виснет**. Виснет из-за того, что вы **дописали уже свой код**. Документация тут не причем)) Спрошу в третий раз: для чего внутри скрипта имеется `private GameObject copys;` и инстациирование объекта в эту переменную?

Comment: Хорошо, давайте рассмотрим только этот код

Comment: public GameObject pref; // Use this for initialization void Start() { Instantiate(pref, new Vector3(10, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity); }

Comment: Если pref - это тот же самый объект, на котором навешан NewBehaviourScript - тоже проблемка. Попробуйте инстанциирование сделать в другом скрипте, в который уже впихивать префаб элемента

Comment: Хорошо попробую.

Comment: Да работает, спасибо разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

***Если pref - это тот же самый объект, на котором навешан NewBehaviourScript - тоже проблемка. Попробуйте инстанциирование сделать в другом скрипте, в который уже впихивать префаб элемента – Алексей Шиманский***

Comment: @ АлексейШиманский Было ли выдано разрешение на цитирование комментария в ответе?

Comment: @0xdb я бы не обиделся даже если б не цитировали))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Добрейшей души Вы юноша))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/27/178988. Только я не понимаю, ответ это или нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy  да, это ответ. Если бы ТС своими словами написал его в чуть более развернутом виде -  сомнений не было, конечно)

Comment: to Алексей Шиманский, да Ваш ответ верен, я его и выделил. До меня дошло, что при создании клона объекта, если на нем был скрипт, то он и запустился.